# Code to check it credits cause range error?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
print("counting in twenties") 
for i in range (0,120,20):
    print(i)
if i != (0,120,20):
    print(“range error”)
```

Can someone help me with the code as the outcome is not correct. It  gives me range error for any value I type it should only give range error if the value is not `20,40,60,80,100,120`

Comment: "any value I type"??  There is nowhere in this code that you type a value; it appears to depend on a previously-defined variable, `i`.  If that is not an integer, you're not going to match any integer value.  If you have properly converted input to an integer, then see the posted responses.  If you don't know how to input an integer, then look up that technique: it's covered in several Stack Overflow questions and any Python input tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

> *It gives me range error for any value I type it should only give range error if the value is not 20,40,60,80,100,120*

What you *type* is probably a `string`, make sure you convert it to an `int`. Try the following:

```
val = int(input("Type 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 or 120"))
if val not in range(20, 140, 20):
  print("Range Error, bad value:", val)
else:
  print("You typed:", val)
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/072fa24fcc)

---

Note:

Python is case SeNsiItive, so `Print` isn't the same as `print`

Comment: There's no `input` in the code snippet provided by @Anonymuos12. Moreover, it isn't necessary to use `list()` in your example

Comment: There's no input , but the OP mention *"whatever I type"*, which indicates some sort of user input.

Comment: @Anonymuos12, You're welcome,  If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your given value is in a collection of the desired values:

```
valid = list(range(0, 120, 20))
if i not in valid:
    print("range error")
```

Comment: It still gives me range error for any value I type it should only give range error of the value is not 20,40,60,80,100,120

Comment: Convering that range to a list only makes the code slower and more verbose.

Comment: What you ***"type"*** is most certainly a `string` an you're trying to compare it to an `int`, that's why you've an error. convert the input to and int `int(input("type a value")) ` and try again...